# Put value into cell based on same value being the same in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA macro for an Excel worksheet. I am using a Mac so any code would need to work on Excel for Mac.

The notes below explain what I want to do and then the code will be after these notes. The code works but it isn't efficient because it depends on looping through every player name using the text of the player name instead of just comparing cell values in one column with the cell value in another column. I want the code to just compare the value in column A with the value in column C. If the value in column A equals the value in column C, put the value in column D into the cell for column B. I hope this makes sense, if not please just ask me and I will try to explain it better.

What the macro does:

Column A contains NFL Player Names

Column B is empty

Column C also contains NFL Player Names

Column D contains fantasy points.

The Player Name in column A might equal the Player Name in column C

But the Player Name in column A might NOT EQUAL the Player Name in column C

If the cell value in column A equals the value in column C, regardless of whether or not it is in the same row

Then put the value of column D into the cell for column B that corresponds to the row for column A

For Example. Cell A57 has the value "John Doe"

Cell C99 has the value "John Doe"

Cell D99 has the value "26"
I want the value that is in D99 (i.e. "26") to be put in B57

Cell A654 also has the value "John Doe"

I want the value of D99 (i.e. "26") to be put in B654

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub fantasyPlayer()
Dim rng As Range, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, MyArray As Variant, LastRow As Long, x As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To LastRow
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player1" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D2").Value
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player2" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D3").Value
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player3" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D4").Value
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player4" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D5").Value
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player5" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D6").Value
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player6" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D7").Value
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player7" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D8").Value
        End If
        If ws.Range("A" & x) = "Player8" Then
            ws.Range("B" & x).Value = .Range("D9").Value
        End If
    Next x
End With
   End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you show us your data - it is not clear what your exact question is, see [ask] and [repro]

Comment: Here's a link to a Google spreadsheet that shows my data along with notes on how I want the final result to look like:  [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzStbcCRS77IkGbhaQSofce-n7FPA4iuGjF9gdrmcQo/edit#gid=0[link]

Comment: if you want others to be notifyed about your comments, you have to use @[username]. For what you want you don't need VBA - you can do it with an INDEX/MATCH-Formula - If you google for that you will find a lot of tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Use [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub fantasyPlayer()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyArray As Variant, LastRow As Long
    Dim x As Long, n As Long, ix
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        ' names in col C
        MyArray = .Range("C1:C" & LastRow).Value2
       
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To LastRow
            ' match Ax to Cix
            ix = Application.Match(.Cells(x, "A"), MyArray, 0)
            If Not IsError(ix) Then
                .Cells(x, "B") = .Cells(ix, "D")
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next x
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows matched"
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you. Exactly what I needed.